# Will the replicates of Hadoop occupy NameNode's memory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We know each file in HDFS will occupy about 300 bytes memory in NameNode, because each file has 2 other replicates, so will one file totally occupy 900 bytes memory in NameNode, or the replicates don't occupy memory in NameNode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at optimisation for name node memory usage and performance done at [HADOOP-1687](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1687) can see that the memory usage for **blocks** is multiplied by the replication factor. However, the memory usage for **files** and **directories** does not have increased cost based on replication.

The number of bytes used for a block prior to that change (i.e. in Hadoop 0.13) was 152 + 72 * replication, giving a figure of 368 bytes per block with the default replication setting of 3. Files were typically using 250 bytes, and directories 290 bytes, both regardless of replication setting.

The improvements were included from 0.15 (which did include some per-replication saving, but there was still a per-replication cost).

I haven't seen any other references indicating the per-replication memory usage has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Hadoop Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NameNode):  "It keeps the directory tree of all files in the file system, and tracks where across the cluster the file data is kept. It does not store the data of these files itself."

The NameNode stores only file and directory information.  With a replication factor of 3, a 300 MB file placed into HDFS will use a total of 900 MB of raw disk space.  Each DataNode will get one copy of the 300 MB file, stored on disk not in memory.

Comment: Hi Chris, you misunderstood my question. I mean that will the replicates consume "Meta data space" in NameNode memory. e.g Namenode will create some meta data for each file in namenode memory. But for the replicates NN create meta for them as well please?